# RadTextBox Enter Key Closes the Browser Tab

Tags: telerik, radtextbox

I am having a RadTextBox in my page. This control is one of the search criteria to bring the results. The issue is, if I focus on the text box and press enter, the browser window / tab closes immediately. The RadTextBox tag does not have anything other than the runat, ID attributes.

Please share if you have faced a similar issue like this and found a solution.

[image]

Source Code:

```
    <%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="True" Inherits="Controls_ProductListControl_ProductListControl"
    CodeBehind="ProductListControl.ascx.cs" ClientIDMode="AutoID" %>
    <%@ Register Assembly="Telerik.Web.UI" Namespace="Telerik.Web.UI" TagPrefix="telerik" %>

    <telerik:RadScriptBlock ID="RadScriptBlock1" runat="server">
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        ProductList = {
            openAdd: function (catID) {
                PopupWindow.open('/ProductCatalog/Popups/AddNewProductDialog.aspx?PID=0&PAID=0&CID=' + catID, 960, 700, ProductList.refreshGrid);
                return false;
            },
            refreshGrid: function () {
                $find("<%= RadAjaxManager.GetCurrent(Page).ClientID %>").ajaxRequest("refreshGrid");
            },
            onRequestStart: function (sender, args) {
                if (args.get_eventTarget().indexOf("ExportToExcelButton") >= 0 ||
                    args.get_eventTarget().indexOf("ExportToWordButton") >= 0 ||
                    args.get_eventTarget().indexOf("ExportToCsvButton") >= 0 ||
                    args.get_eventTarget().indexOf("ExportToPdfButton") >= 0) {
                    args.set_enableAjax(false);
                }
            }
        }
    </script>
</telerik:RadScriptBlock>
    <div class="heading">
    <telerik:RadAjaxManagerProxy ID="RadAjaxManagerProxy1" runat="server">
        <AjaxSettings>
            <telerik:AjaxSetting AjaxControlID="LinkButtonSearch">
                <UpdatedControls>
                    <telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl ControlID="RadGridProducts" />
                </UpdatedControls>
            </telerik:AjaxSetting>
            <telerik:AjaxSetting AjaxControlID="LinkButtonShowAll">
                <UpdatedControls>
                    <telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl ControlID="RadGridProducts" />
                </UpdatedControls>
            </telerik:AjaxSetting>
            <telerik:AjaxSetting AjaxControlID="RadGridProducts">
                <UpdatedControls>
                    <telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl ControlID="RadGridProducts" />
                </UpdatedControls>
            </telerik:AjaxSetting>
        </AjaxSettings>
    </telerik:RadAjaxManagerProxy>

    <asp:Label ID="LabelProductName" runat="server" Text="<%$ Resources:UI, ProductListControl_Text_LabelProductName %>" />
    <telerik:RadTextBox ID="RadTextBoxProductName" runat="server" MaxLength="50"></telerik:RadTextBox>
    <asp:Label ID="LabelProductID" runat="server" Text="<%$ Resources:UI, ProductListControl_Text_LabelProductID %>" />
    <telerik:RadNumericTextBox ID="RadNumericTextBoxProductID" runat="server" Width="100px"
        DataType="System.Int32" MaxLength="9" MaxValue="999999999" MinValue="1" Style="text-align: center">
        <NumberFormat DecimalDigits="0" GroupSeparator="" />
    </telerik:RadNumericTextBox>
    <asp:Label ID="LabelRuleID" runat="server" Text="<%$ Resources:UI, ProductListControl_Text_LabelRuleID %>" Visible="false" />
    <telerik:RadTextBox ID="RadTextBoxRuleID" runat="server" Visible="false" />
    <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButtonSearch" runat="server" OnClick="LinkButtonSearch_Click"><%= Resources.UI.ProductListControl_HTML_Search %></asp:LinkButton>
    <asp:placeholder ID="Placeholder2" runat="server"><img src="<%= Resources.UI.ProductListControl_HTML_ImagesSearchPng %>" width="14" height="14" alt="<%= Resources.UI.ProductListControl_HTML_Search_1 %>" /></asp:placeholder>
      &nbsp;
      <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButtonShowAll" runat="server" OnClick="LinkButtonShowAll_Click"><%= Resources.UI.ProductListControl_HTML_ShowAll %>    </asp:LinkButton>
    &nbsp;
      <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButtonAddNew" runat="server"><%= Resources.UI.ProductListControl_HTML_AddNewProduct %></asp:LinkButton>
    &nbsp;
      <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButtonCopyProducts" runat="server" OnClientClick="window.open('/ProductCatalog/CopyProducts.aspx?catid=0','CopyProducts');"><%= Resources.UI.ProductListControl_HTML_CopyProducts %></asp:LinkButton>
</div>
     <br />
     <div class="fullrow">
      <telerik:RadGrid ID="RadGridProducts" runat="server" AllowPaging="True"     AllowSorting="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" GridLines="None" OnNeedDataSource="RadGridProducts_NeedDataSource" Visible="False" Skin="Windows7" OnItemDataBound="RadGridProducts_ItemDataBound">
        <MasterTableView>
            <RowIndicatorColumn>
                <HeaderStyle Width="20px"></HeaderStyle>
            </RowIndicatorColumn>
            <ExpandCollapseColumn>
                <HeaderStyle Width="20px"></HeaderStyle>
            </ExpandCollapseColumn>
            <%--<CommandItemSettings ExportToPdfText="<%$ Resources:UI, ProductListControl_ExportToPdfText_ExportToPdf %>"></CommandItemSettings>--%>
            <Columns>
                <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="pcProductId" HeaderText="<%$ Resources:UI, ProductListControl_HeaderText_Product_ID %>" ReadOnly="True" UniqueName="ProductID">
                </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                <telerik:GridHyperLinkColumn DataTextField="ExtProductName" HeaderText="<%$ Resources:UI, ProductListControl_HeaderText_ProductName %>"
                    UniqueName="ProductDetailLink" DataNavigateUrlFields="pcProductId" DataNavigateUrlFormatString="~/ProductCatalog/ProductDetail2.aspx?PID={0}">    </telerik:GridHyperLinkColumn>
       <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="ExtEffectiveDate" DataFormatString="{0:d}"
                    HeaderText="<%$ Resources:UI, ProductListControl_HeaderText_EffectiveDate %>" UniqueName="EffectiveDate"></telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="ExtPositions" HeaderText="<%$ Resources:UI, ProductListControl_HeaderText_ExtPositions %>" ReadOnly="True"
                    UniqueName="Positions"></telerik:GridBoundColumn>
       <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="ExtRatingType" HeaderText="<%$ Resources:UI, ProductListControl_HeaderText_ExtRatingType %>" ReadOnly="True"
                    UniqueName="RatingType"></telerik:GridBoundColumn>
       <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="ExtBaseBillRate" HeaderText="<%$ Resources:UI, ProductListControl_HeaderText_ExtBaseBillRate %>"
                    ReadOnly="True" UniqueName="BaseBillRate" DataFormatString="{0:0.00}" FilterControlWidth="30px">
     </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
     <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="ExtBasePayRate" HeaderText="<%$ Resources:UI, ProductListControl_HeaderText_ExtBasePayRate %>" ReadOnly="True"
                    UniqueName="BasePayRate" DataFormatString="{0:0.00}" FilterControlWidth="30px">
                </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="ExtMargin" HeaderText="<%$ Resources:UI, ProductListControl_HeaderText_ExtMargin %>" ReadOnly="True"
                    UniqueName="Margin" DataFormatString="{0:0.00}"></telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="ExtEntityName" HeaderText="<%$ Resources:UI, ProductListControl_HeaderText_ExtEntityName %>" ReadOnly="True"
                    UniqueName="EntityName"></telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="ExtProductStatus" HeaderText="<%$ Resources:UI, ProductListControl_HeaderText_ExtProductStatus %>" UniqueName="Status">
                </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
            </Columns>
        </MasterTableView>
        <HeaderContextMenu EnableImageSprites="True" CssClass="GridContextMenu GridContextMenu_Default">
        </HeaderContextMenu>
    </telerik:RadGrid></div>
```

Thanks,
Sriram

Comment: Which browser? Which platform? Which version of Telerik? Where is your code? How are we supposed to help without any information?

Comment: Sharing the details below.

1) Using browser IE 10 (Clients are using the same)
2) Windows Server 2008 R2 (64 Bit) - Service Pack 1
2) Telerik version 2013.3.1324.45
3) Shared the code in the main thread